# Node.js child process exec returning : Error: kill EPERM STDERR STDOUT_SIZE

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am exposing and API dedicated to printing logs from a Linux System D service. Here is a sample of the code:

```
'use strict';
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();
router.get('/printlogs', function (req, res) {

//simplified for Stack Overflow
var completeCmd = "sudo journalctl -u node-myapp@serveruser --no-pager --since \"2020-06-31 00:00:00\"";

exec(completeCmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {

    var status = 0;
    var response = "";

    if (error) {
        console.log("Error !");
        console.log("ERROR : " + error);
        console.log("STDERR : " + stderr);
        console.log("STDOUT_SIZE : " + stdout.length);
        status = 500;
        response = stderr;
    } else {
        console.log("Success !");
        status = 200;
        response = stdout;
    }

    res.contentType('text/plain').status(status);
    res.send(response);
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

If the date in "completeCmd" is close enough (ex: last 10 days), everything works... if the date is too far back (ex: 3 months ago), the process fails in a weird way:

```
Error !
ERROR : Error: kill EPERM
STDERR : 
STDOUT_SIZE : 1046013
```

The response is returned in about 187 ms, so it is not a timeout...
Theories:

- Could it be a limitation in the possible size of stdout ?
- Could it be linked to the fact that my command use sudo ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the error message, it looks like the error is because your standard output size is bigger than the default value in NodeJS.

Based on this [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), you can increase the output buffer size as follows:

```
const bufferSize = 1024 * 2048; // (default 1024 * 1024, double up)
exec(command, {maxBuffer: bufferSize}, function(error, stdout, stderr){ 
  callback(error, stdout); 
});
```

Furthermore, you can always [check the output byte size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46959664/2329659) to confirm that bufferSize is the problem. This helps to determine if the `maxBuffer` needs to be incremented.

Comment: Man... I read the doc, but missed this. I will try it out ASAP.